# localStorage vs. Cookies

Tags: express, cookies, local-storage

I understand Cookies and localStorage to an extent where user data such as preferences etc. can be stored. However, I'm confused as to what advantage over another each one of them brings.

Is there an advantage to using Cookies vs localStorage, or the other way round? Am I introducing vulnerabilities by using localStorage?